# Where does a file downloaded with CURL go on the file system?

Tags: curl

Ive downloaded a file from this site with the following curl command:

https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

```
# Copy/paste the command below into your terminal to begin downloading all the required files
# Don't have cURL or want to learn more, visit http://curl.haxx.se/

curl -O -L "https://www.modern.ie/vmdownload?platform=mac&virtPlatform=virtualbox&browserOS=IE10-Win8.1&parts=5&filename=VMBuild_20131127/VirtualBox/IE10_Win8/Mac/IE10.Win8.For.MacVirtualBox.part{1.sfx,2.rar,3.rar,4.rar,5.rar}"
```

Where does the file actually go? I cant seem to see it anywhere on my machine.

Comment: look for a file named `vmdownload` in the directory where you ran that statement.

Comment: @Darth Android, I believe that `vmdownload` is a cgi script with the ? providing options into it.

Comment: @Bill Correct! Which is what `curl` will use as the name when saving the result of requesting that script. On the HTTP level, the file being requested is `https://www.modern.id/vmdownload`, so `vmdownload` is the name that `curl` wants to use. The rest is just parameters `curl` is sending to the server, so it doesn't factor into the naming of the file.

Comment: @Darth Android, at the end of the parameters there are 5 parts specified however.  How would those be handled with their partial names?  `curl` can't be so brain-dead as to call them the name of the script instead of their proper names?

Comment: @Bill How is `curl` supposed to know that those parameters are the filename? You could use the parameter called `filename` for anything - maybe the name of the file to upload; What if the website uses `name` or `fname` instead? There's no standards for any of this, so there's no way for `curl` to know what the filename might be, other than the script name. `curl` doesn't even know that it's calling a script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will type or paste that command into a terminal.  In the folder the terminal is in when the command is executed the files will be placed in.

Comment: If I close the terminal without running the command, is the file still somewhere on my system?

Comment: @jdln If you do not run the command, then the file is no where on your system.

Comment: But the file is downloaded. Is it only in RAM?

Comment: @jdln The file is not downloaded unless you run the command. The command downloads the file; if you do not run the command, then it cannot download the file.